# What do you call it when someone stops you from daydreaming?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

When you're building castles in the air absentmindedly, daydreaming, or looking at nothing with an empty mind, or maybe being absorbed in thought. Then someone comes over and "wakes you up", stopping you from musing on things.

From what I can describe, he might pat you on the back, or say, "*Hey, what's wrong?*" And you'd be like, getting startled or diverting your sight/attention, or maybe smiling.

**Question:**

What do you call it, the thing he does and the thing your respond to what he does?

Comment: [Porlocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_from_Porlock)?   :)

Comment: Doesn't that mean "to interrupt or intrude at an awkward moment"? Is daydreaming "awkward"?

Comment: From wikipedia, *Thus "person from Porlock", "man from Porlock", or just "Porlock" are literary allusions to unwanted intruders who disrupt inspired creativity.*  (Not an exact fit to your question, but related enough it seemed to be worth a comment.)

Comment: I call it very rude!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What comes to my mind is

- Bring one back to reality/real world

and what you do is

- snapping out of it

If I look up "snap out of if" it mentions negative things like depression, but I am quite convinced you can *snap out of* a daydream

Answer (score 1):

I think we could call it **a stark awakening**

Comment: it could be done gently too

Answer (score 1):

I’m surprised no one has mentioned *[reverie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reverie#English):*

> A state of dreaming while awake; a loose or irregular train of thought; musing or meditation; daydream.

It’s relatively common in writing to use *break* with *reverie*, in various ways:

- A sudden flash of light **broke** my reverie
- He **broke** me **out of** my reverie with his question
- The sound of the door **broke into** my reverie

Answer (score 0):

You could use **somnus interruptus**, which has bit of a naughty ring to it.

Answer (score -1):

Penny for your thoughts?

Is the usual friendly way to do it.

> It's an expression meaning you'd like to know what someone is thinking
>   about, maybe if they seem to be daydreaming or have their head in the
>   clouds.
>   **[Yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090910063523AAskFwq)**